# Question about degrees of freedom in an independent sample t-test

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

I've been asked the following question by a scientist who is not a statistician: Suppose we take a sample $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ from a population that we can assume is normal (I don't think this assumption is critical). We then calculate the sample mean $\bar x$ and variance $s^2$. We then take a different sample $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ from an unknown (normal) population, and what we are trying to test is whether or not the two samples could be from the same population.

I would like to give the scientist who asked me the question a simple test, so my thinking was to give them a prediction interval for the mean $\bar y$ of the sample of size m. We can let the null hypothesis be that they are from the same population, and alternative hypothesis that they are not. Under the null hypothesis, $(\bar x - \bar y)/(\sigma \sqrt{1/n + 1/m}) \sim N(0,1)$, where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of our initial population. However, as usual, we don't know $\sigma^2$. The standard thing to do here would be to use the t-distribution, take a weighted mean of the sample variances of the $x$'s and $y$'s as an estimate for $\sigma^2$, and take $n+m-2$ as the degrees of freedom.

I don't want to do that, though, since in fact in this situation there will be many possible populations that the sample could be from and I want the test to be simple (i.e. not require him to calculate the variance of the $y$'s, take the weighted means of the variances, calculate the degrees of freedom, put everything in the $t$ distribution, etc.), so what I want to do is to give him a prediction interval for $\bar y$ for each population which is calculated without use of the sample variance of $y_1, \ldots, y_m$. My thinking is to simply use $s^2$, the sample variance of the $x$'s, as an estimate for the variance $\sigma^2$, and then approximately  $(\bar x - \bar y)/(s \sqrt{1/n + 1/m}) \sim t_r$. My question then is, what is the degrees of freedom $r$? My feeling is that $n+m-2$ is too optimistic, because $s^2$ was calculated with a sample of size only $n$, and that therefore $n-1$ is the correct value. This seems basically to agree with what is done in Chapter 2 of "Predictive Inference: An Introduction" by Geisser, except that there only $m=1$ is done in this fashion, and the rest is somewhat different.

Has anyone seen this question before? A reference would be great.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degrees of freedom of the t will come from the d.f. used in calculating $s$

So if you assume the variances are equal and to estimate the variance you use $\hat{\sigma^2}=s^2_x$ the d.f. in the $t$ will be $n-1$ just as you suggest.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. So I was right. Do you happen to know a good reference for this fact?

Comment: Not explicitly about doing what you're asking but exactly the same theory as the usual test applies. If you have $T=Z/\sqrt{Q/\nu}$ where $Z$ is standard normal and $Q$ is chi-squared with $\nu$ d.f and independent of $Z$ then $T$ is distributed as $t$ with $\nu$ degrees of freedom (note that any scale factor $\sigma$ will cancel out of numerator and denominator). This [standard result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Characterization) may be found in any number of university texts on probability distributions / mathematical statistics. ... ctd

Comment: ctd.. You're already assuming those conditions all hold (either directly or they're implied by what you were already assuming) here. For example, for $X$ you're assuming they're iid normal, so $\bar{X}$ is independent of $s^2_x$. You were already assuming independence of $X_i$ and $Y_j$ by implication (referencing the two sample t-test) so numerator and denominator are independent; you were already assuming they had a common variance for the same reason,  and so on. So we can directly apply the linked characterization of the $t$ distribution.

Comment: Beautiful, I've got it now. Makes perfect sense. Many thanks for your help on this.